Chrome Extension Developing Error: Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15
I'm working on a learning project with a fork of a Chrome Browser Extension and
I can't register the service worker (background.js) to my chrome browser.
another error I see in the chrome://extensions Error Stack is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
in dist/background.js:1 (anonymous function)

I'm using Chrome Version 131.0.6778.140 (Official Build) (arm64) for
MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (M2 Processor).
I've loaded this into my Chrome Browser in developer mode and as Unpacked by pointing Chrome extensions to the following directory on my local machine:
/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/GitHub/Furigana

this is the cloned (forked) directory.

Please see my fork here.

Note that I'm in the process of migrating this project form a Manifest V2 to V3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I've detailed my question and I've included my codebase here.
I'm trying to load a Chrome extension into my browser, but get an error.

You need to compile/build it using npm i && npm run build because require() is not a browser API. Refer to tutorials on how to install nodejs that also installs npm.
